# What is the rule of "complete action using.." dialog of Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

There is a "always" option on the "complete action using.." dialog. I'm wondering what's the matching rules if the same intent sent next time? Will it be the exact same intent or only the same action, category data value? or else?

Answer (score 2):

Everything will be the same the second time, however Android will pass the intent to the app you selected always on, instead of presenting a selection of apps which can handle that intent.

Path 1 - No default:
Android system gets intent, checks what apps are registered to receive that. Checks if any of them are the "default" for that intent. Displays a list of all of them, sending the intent to what you select.

Path 2 - A default is set:
 Part A - No new apps:
 Same as 1, but it finds a default app and sends the intent directly there, without the list of options.
 Part B - New app installed:
 Same as 2A, but the system sees a new app was installed that can handle the intent that was not there last time, so it displays the list of all compatible apps again.

Comment: "Everything will be the same the second time" means every value of every field should be the same? I observed in a lot of cases that the value of DATA field has little changes, the Intent will still be sent to the default app.